# How to get customized bytes from /dev/urandom?

Tags: c, random, byte, bitcoin, puzzle

I am working on a program that finds partial collision in Bitcoin addresses.
I have obtained source code for urandom and don't see where to start.
So I want to get random bytes from /dev/urandom of length 32 in total (including the masking 0s) because my program expects 256 bit but masked with zeros at the beginning when converted to hex.

The hex output would be like this

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002d4
```

Notice the 0s before the actual Hex value( that's what I am calling a mask), in python it is needed by many libraries to get Bitcoin address.

I am struggling with the following code (not from random.c), now I think modifying urandom itself could be more helpful.

```
   static bool init_rand(void *data, size_t size)
{
    FILE *stream = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");
    if (stream == NULL)
        return false;
    bool ok = (fread(data, sizeof(uint8_t), size, stream) == size);
    fclose(stream);
    return ok;
}



static bool init_rand(void *data, size_t size)
{
    size_t size0 = size / sizeof(unsigned) + 1;
    assert(size0 * sizeof(unsigned) >= size);
    unsigned data0[size0];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size0; i++)
    {
        int err = rand_s(data0 + i);
        if (err != 0)
            return false;
    }
    memcpy(data, data0, size);
    return true;
}


static struct seed *make_seed(void)
{
    struct seed *seed = (struct seed *)malloc(sizeof(struct seed));
    assert(seed != NULL);
    seed->counter = 0;
    if (!init_rand(seed, sizeof(struct seed)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: failed to init random seed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (seed->counter == 0)     // Sanity check...
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: random seed initialization failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return seed;
}
```

For Full code please see Pairgen [Here](https://github.com/basil00/pairgen/blob/master/pairgen.c).

Is it possible to modify random.c from Linux kernel drivers to produce bytes already masked with 0s?

Comment: Just how big do you think an `unsigned char` is?

Comment: Confused. You say you want "random bytes of length 32", but give a sample that is 65 nibbles long.... Do you mean 32.5 random bytes? (that won't be random anymore if you change them arbitrarily.)

Comment: @fe203 I want bytes of length 32 in total(24 zeros and 8 random)

Comment: I am sorry, does 0s count in bytes or not

Comment: Your code is so far off from correct C and from the goal you express that it is hard to know what to say about it. You are apparently trying to limit the selection of random numbers. To do that, you might simply create a buffer of 32 bytes, initialize it with zeros, and then fill in 12 bits, or whatever amount you want, with a random data. That is fairly easy to do, but the context of your `init_rand` routine is unclear.

Comment: If that is what you want, then simply use `memset` to set `size` bytes in `data` to zero, define a `uint16_t` object, fill the `uint16_t` object with data from `/dev/urandom`, mask the `uint16_t` object with `0xfffu` to limit it to 12 bits, and then copy the `uint16_t` object over two of the bytes in `data`.

Comment: E.g., sample code might be, in part, `memset(data, 0, size); uint16_t x; fread(&x, sizeof x, 1); x &= 0xfffu; memcpy(data + size - sizeof x, &x, sizeof x);`, assuming you want the random bits at the “end” of the buffer (the high-addressed part). But `memcpy(data, &x, sizeof x);`, which puts them at the start, might suffice for whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: @EricPostpischil that is exactly what I need, but I am not much in C that's why I am here, plus the above code is from Pairgen which is available to modify, please put that answer it's going the better way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250791/discussion-between-diviserbyzero-and-eric-postpischil).

Comment: @diviserbyzero if you're not much in C, consider if changing 'urandom' implementation is the right task for you. I suggest starting with learning how computers work, no offense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`memset` is what can mask bytes with zeroes. that helped me  except i had to do it in `rand256(seed)` function though

```
static uint256_t rand256(struct seed *seed)
{
    seed->counter++;
    return sha256(seed, sizeof(struct seed));
}

static uint256_t rand256_and_mask(struct seed *seed)
{
    //Generate 256-bit random number using rand256 function
    uint256_t r = rand256(seed);
    memset(&r, 0, 24); //mask first  bytes leaving 8 intact
    return r;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You are confusing printed representation ("the hex output") with an actual value.

0x2d4 and 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002d4 are the exact same value.

"0x2d4" and "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002d4" are two very different strings.

If you want to format a string - use formating operations (like `sprintf`).

---

Looking at your comments, it appears that you're misunderstanding the concept of `0` and what "hex" means.

Hex stands for Hexadecimal, meaning the interpretation of the value in the base-16 system. It is used to *represent* the value (for readability), it doesn't affect the value itself. For example, `0xA` is the base-16 representation of the decimal value `10`. These are the same value, written differently.

Similarly, leading zeroes don't change the value. If you see `0x24b` in your debugger, and the variable holding it is 32 bits, then the actual memory representation would be `0x0000024b`. You can control how the value is *printed* using the `printf` formatting flags.

Last but not least, `0` is a valid value. Every bit can be either `0` or `1`, and you can have a random generator provide you an absolutely valid randomly generated value which is `0` for all the 256 bits you asked for. While highly unlikely, it is not impossible. Much more likely is that *some* of the 256 bits would be `0`, and it is entirely possible that some of them would be the highest bits, leading your 256 bit value to be misinterpreted as less than 256 bits if you discard these high bits (as `printf` does by default).

When used for cryptographic purposes, you should not manipulate the values you read from `urandom` as this would most likely introduce vulnerabilities and is probably not what you *really* want to do.

Comment: Hex is 4 bits meaning 2d4 is 12 bits and it's 1,5 byte. So I have edited the question coz I need the output to be equal to 32 bytes including masking (0s), 8 bytes without masking 0s but I want urandom to mask it for me

Comment: @diviserbyzero `hex is 4 bits` - what does that mean? Hex means base 16, it has nothing to do with bits. If you need a 32 bits random value - read 32 bits. What does "mask" mean for you here?

Comment: zeros at the beginning, that's what I am calling mask

Comment: @diviserbyzero beginning of what? You're trying to print it out?

Comment: my apologies I am not trying to print anything but I need to read bytes customized from /dev/random

Comment: In the form of less than 256 bit, let's say 8.25 bytes but when those byte are converted to hex I would prepend the 0s to make them 64 characters in length

Comment: If you need a 256 bit random value - then read all the 256 bits from `urandom` and use them as is. If you need 66 bits random value (8.25 bytes, assuming your byte is 8 bits) - then you need to do some bitwise operations to manipulate it. But then you end your comment with `make them 64 characters in length` which suggest string representation. So what is it that you actually need?

Comment: @diviserbyzero to you understand that 0x24b, 0x00024b and 0x00000024b are exactly the same value?

Comment: @yes but the visual appearance is different though

Comment: These bytes will be used as private key, a private is 64 hex characters long so 2d4 will be 61 0s plus 2d4

Comment: how do you represent 0 in bytes? Let's say I need 1 byte read from urandom, let's say it's 0F so I want an output with value 0F but visually presented as (31 zeroes)+0F That's all I need

Comment: @diviserbyzero read the documentation for `printf`, specifically for the `%d` flag.

Comment: Re “introduce vulnerabilities and is probably not what you *really* want to do”: Yes, it is. The question states “I am working on a program that finds partial collision in Bitcoin addresses”; the OP is exploring hypothetical vulnerabilities. It is a learning exercise.

Comment: @littleadv: Re “hex is 4 bits - what does that mean?”: One hexadecimal digit is equivalent to four binary digits. OP requests that when `init_rand` is called with 32 for `size` that the buffer `data` be filled with 32 bytes of zeros except for 12 bits that are randomly drawn from a uniform distribution over the possible values of 12 bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm sure you're smart, you don't have to prove anything to me. If the OP cannot even formulate their own requirements and is asking if 0 is a valid value, looking for vulnerability in Bitcoin code is probably a bit much a challenge for them.

Comment: @littleadv a Bitcoin private key is always of length 64 hexadecimal char, bit address.org can confirm that, whether it's value is less than 256 it doesn't matter, so I know how computers work and I will shed some light on you.

Comment: The referenced program contain an algorithm called birthday attack combined with Distinguished point and it works perfectly in 256 bit space( I mean with number ranging from 2**255 to 2**256-1) but I now need to run it on numbers in lower.

Comment: I don't think bits work they way you think they do. 256 bit space includes values [0..2**256).